# Allow column overlap in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, alignat

I'd like to typeset equations to look something like this:

[image]

The columns are aligned at the `mapsto` and `\text{if}` sections, but since the first column of the fourth line is too long, and it has no second column, it is allowed to spill into the second column.

Is this possible using `align`, `alignat`, `flalign` or something similar?

Comment: you can use `\mathrlap{...}` from the `mathtools` package.  (`mathtools` loads `amsmath`, which you're obviously already using.)

Comment: Perfect! Write as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to "hide" the width of the too-long segment you can use `\mathrlap{...}`
from the `mathtools` package.

(`mathtools` loads `amsmath`, which you're obviously already using.)

Comment: Is it possible to declare this for multiple lines? Instead of wrapping each line around \mathrlap{...}

Comment: i can't think of a way to handle multiple lines, but i also don't know exactly how you coded your input for your example.  that's why i didn't give an example in the answer.